# For a module $M$ one has $rad(M)=0$ if and only if $M$ is isomorphic to a submodule of a direct product of simple modules

Tags: modules, semi-simple-rings

*Definition:* For a module $M$, the intersection of all the maximal submodules and module $M$ is called as radical of the module and denoted by $rad(M)$.

**For a module $M$ one has $rad(M)=0$ if and only if $M$ is isomorphic to a submodule of a direct product of simple modules.**

Above statement is written in a review report of a well reputed journal. I have doubt about the validity of above statement. Please clarify it to me.

*My thought:*  submodule of a direct product of simple modules is semisimple and so $M$ will be semisimple if and only if $rad(M)=0$ (according to above statement). Which is not true in general. For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ has zero radical but not semisimple.

Comment: You are mistaken when claiming essentially that direct *products* of simple modules are semisimple. By definition a semisimple module is one that is isomorphic to a direct **sum** of simples, not to a direct product. Arbitrary direct products of simple modules are not necessarily semisimple and neither are their submodules.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this mistake. Can you suggest how to prove above statement?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying. Given an arbitrary *left* $A$-module $M$ over arbitrary ring $A$ and arbitrary submodule $N \leqslant_A M$ write $\sigma^M_N \colon M \to M/N$ for the canonical surjection onto the respective quotient module. Consider the *direct product in restricted sense* $\rho$ of the family of canonical surjections $\sigma^M_N$ where $N$ ranges through the set $\mathscr{M}$ of *maximal* submodules of $M$ (which might be empty, depending on the structure of $M$). This map is $A$-linear, defined on $M$ and *(to be cont.)*

Comment: *(cont.)* and having $\displaystyle \prod_{N \in \mathscr{M}} M/N$ as codomain. Since all the members $N$ of $\mathscr{M}$ are maximal, it follows that the quotients $M/N$ are simple and by elementary properties of direct products in restricted sense it follows that $\mathrm{Ker} \rho=\mathrm{Rad}(M)$. Thus, by a direct application of the (iso)morphism theorem it follows that in general the quotient $M/\mathrm{Rad}(M)$ embeds into a direct *product* of simple $A$-modules. This settles the reverse direction of the equivalence you inquire about. As for the forward direction, *(to be cont. 2)*

Comment: *(cont. 2)* recall the general proposition that given an $A$-linear map $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{A-\mathrm{Mod}}}(M, N)$ we have in general $f[\mathrm{Rad}(M)] \subseteq \mathrm{Rad}(N)$. This entails that for an arbitrary *family* $M$ of $A$-modules indexed by an arbitrary set $I$ the relation $\mathrm{Rad}\left(\displaystyle \prod_{i \in I}M_i\right) \subseteq \displaystyle \prod_{i \in I}\mathrm{Rad}(M_i)$ holds and therefore in particular that radicals of direct *products* of *simple* modules are null. *(to be cont. 3)*

Comment: *(cont. 3)* The same general proposition entails that if module $M$ embeds in $M'$ where $\mathrm{Rad}(M')$ is trivial then $\mathrm{Rad}(M)$ is also trivial, and this applies specifically under the leading hypothesis that $M$ embeds in a direct product of simple modules (whose radical is indeed null, as mentioned above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{N_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\kappa\}$ is an indexing of the maximal submodules of $M$, then the canonical map $M\to \prod_{\alpha\in\kappa} M/N_\alpha$ has kernel $rad(M)$.

If $rad(M)$ is zero this is injective so that $M$ is a submodule of the product of simple modules.

It is important not to confuse *sums* of modules with *products*. When the index set is infinite, they can be quite different.

Actually in the scenario above, since the projections on each coordinate are onto $M/N_\alpha$, there is another common terminology: one says that $M$ is the *subdirect product* of the $M/N_\alpha$s.